# Event Propagation in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native-maps, event-propagation

I'm working with a map in react-native-maps that displays a number of Polygons. Each polygon has listeners and the map itself has listeners. On click, I'd like to either highlight a polygon or drop a marker if the click happens where there is no polygon. Unfortunately, I'm not seeing a way to stopPropagation after a polygon click. For now, I'm just using a setTimeout to disable new markers from being made for .5 secs after a polygon is clicked.
Is there a more graceful solution that I'm not aware of. I was unable to get event.stopPropagation to work with the event react-native-maps sends back.